# Почему не запускается .net приложение в Docker'е?

Tags: c#, docker, .net-core, webapi

Пытаюсь разобраться с докером. Иду по тутору https://habr.com/ru/post/332582/.
Шаблонный web-api запускается из основной системы командой  `dotnet .\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\publish\Practice.dll`
Сделала такой Dockerfile:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:runtime
COPY /bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/publish /testapp 
WORKDIR /testapp
EXPOSE 5000
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet"," chrook.dll "]
```

После запуска `docker run -p 5001:5001 -p 5000:5000 my-service:1.0` обратиться к api невозможно. Почему?

Comment: Почему если точка входа у вас Practice.dll вы указали chrook.dll?

Comment: также `microsoft/dotnet:runtime` это рантайм для `.NET Core 2.1` а у вас проект, судя по всему 3.1

Comment: @AzizUmarov, действительно, ошиблась. Но после исправления всё равно не работает - контейнер кажется останавливается сразу после запуска.

Comment: @ExplodingKitten, действительно 3.1, а что нужно указать тогда?

Comment: для 3.1 - `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/runtime:3.1` подробнее https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-dotnet-core

Comment: Собрать образ получилось, но контейнер всё равно не запускается, при запуске пишет `It was not possible to find any installed .NET Core SDKs
  Did you mean to run .NET Core SDK commands? Install a .NET Core SDK from:
      https://aka.ms/dotnet-download`. Почему он вообще просит SDK?

Comment: `FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1-buster-slim`